# Drupal, Views: how to avoid duplicated?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

How can I avoid duplicates on my Drupal View ?

Should I add a filter specifying that a particular field (i.e. userID) should not appear twice ? I cannot find such option

View
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/view1.png
View edit
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/view2.png

thanks

Comment: Could you post a sample view so we can see how the dulpicates are getting in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the configuration screen of the view under basic settings you can try to set "Distinct" to Yes. That might help.

Comment: For Drupal 7 users, this option is available underneath "Query settings" in the "Other" section of the view editor.

Comment: How would one add distinct to a particular field?